# Vector calculus: divergence and curl task

Tags: calculus

***Task:***
$\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf G$ are vector fields and $h=$ scalar function: $\mathbf F + \nabla\times G = \nabla h + \nabla^2 \mathbf F$ (Note: $\mathbf F$ no source: $\nabla\cdot\mathbf F=0)$

- Show that $h$ fulfills Laplacian: $\nabla^2 h=0$.
  (Hint: take half divergence then use curl and divergence calculus.)

*+ English isn't my motherlanguage. Therefore some words might be wrong. Sorry.*

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you have

$$\mathbf{F} + \nabla \times \mathbf{G} = \nabla h + \nabla^2\mathbf{F}$$

you can make $\nabla^2 h$ appear by taking the divergence. Once you take the divergence on both sides you have

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} + \nabla \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{G} = \nabla^2 h + \nabla \cdot \nabla^2 \mathbf{F}.$$

Now remember that the divergence of curl is always zero and that by hypothesis $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 0$ so that

$$\nabla^2 h + \nabla \cdot \nabla^2 \mathbf{F} = 0.$$

Finally, recall that $\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \nabla(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}) - \nabla^2 \mathbf{F}$. Now because $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} =0$ this allows you to substitute

$$\nabla^2 \mathbf{F} = -\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{F},$$

so that

$$\nabla^2 h - \nabla \cdot \left(\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{F}\right) = 0.$$

But again, the divergence of any curl is zero, and so you get

$$\nabla^2 h = 0.$$